# Bootcamp drivers for windows 10

Tags: bootcamp, windows, driver, sound-volume

So, I just installed windows 10, upgraded from a copy of windows 7. After the upgrade, the trackpad didn't work, the volume worked for a little bit and now it is gone. The other keys that control screen brightness, key backlights, etc. do not work also.

It seems the support drivers did not install when I installed windows 7. I upgraded to windows 10 without knowing this.

I've tried to download the windows 10 drivers from bootcamp, but it only downloads the windows 7 drivers. At first I didn't know this and when I went to install them, it said that I needed to revert back to windows 7 to install the drivers.

Is this my only option? To revert back to windows 7 and then reinstall windows 10? Is there anyone who knows or can upload the windows 10 support drivers?

If it helps, my bootcamp version is 6.0.1. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did the Windows 10 install activate? What is the model/year of your Mac? Best option is to download the "Boot Camp Support Software" to a flash drive using the Boot Camp Assistant. Whether or not to use the Boot Camp Assistant to install windows 10 depends on the model of your Mac.

Answer (score 1):

David Anderson's comment is on target, some Macs do not support Windows 10. Annoying but true. So we gotta know what Mac you have.

As an aside you can download the bootcamp.app and then right (or control) click on it and "Show Package Contents." There will be a .zip file in there somewhere (possibly an .exe, sorry it's been a while...) with all the drivers in it that you can then copy to the Windows partition and install. But that working will depend on if that package has the drivers for your specific make and model of Mac.

Also some people have had luck going into device manager in Windows and finding the make and model of the "missing" hardware and installing "generic" versions of those drivers directly from the manufacturers website. EG A video card from NVidia you would get off the NVidia website, not Apple's.

Comment: Your answer is somewhat discouraging. It is my understanding that Macs running Windows 7 - 64 bit or better are upgrading to Windows 10 without any problems. My 2011 iMac upgraded to Windows 10 over the internet. I upgraded my 2007 iMac to Windows 10 - 64 bit from Windows 7 - 64 bit using a DVD, then erased Windows and did a clean install using the "Boot Camp Support Software" designed for 32 bit Windows 7. I thought the Macs that Apple says officially support Windows 10 are installing in EFI mode and that Apple does not officially support BIOS installs of Windows 10. But I could be wrong.

Comment: You will need to verify that Apple made windows 10 compatible drivers for your Mac at https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204990

Comment: All the drivers Apple supplies for previous versions of Windows are compatible with Windows 10. This has been true going back to the 1980's. This precedes the creation of iMac's. This precedes Windows itself. This was true back in the days when the operating system was called OS/2.

Comment: I am not trying to say a driver from the 1980's would work with Windows 10. There is always a point where a legacy driver can not be used. The point is that getting a older computer to work with a newer version of Windows is easier than getting a new computer to work with an older version of Windows. Newer versions of Windows have knowledge of older hardware and drivers. It is not always possible for older versions of Windows to have knowledge of future hardware designs. Although many times newer hardware can operate in a legacy mode for compatibility purposes.